# createAlias - how to specify LEFT join's ON condition in GORM?

Tags: grails, left-join, grails-orm

I am facing a situation where the default `LEFT join` is joining on the undesired condition by default and I want to explicitly define it, how can I do it?

e.g. `createAlias('fault.tgmap', 'tg', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)` picks up the the wrong column i.e. group_id instead of fault_id by default (note that tg has two columns `fault_id` and `group_id`) in the resulting sql query.

How can I explicitly specify that ON which condition the join should happen i.e. `fault.id = tgmap.fault_id instead of fault.id = tgmap.group_id?`

To give domain specific information, trace, fault and tracegroup16 are the domain tables.

```
def results = trace.list(max:max, offset:offset) {      

        createAlias('fault', 'fault',CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        createAlias('fault.tgmap', 'tg', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        createAlias('tg.traceGroup16','tr', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        projections
        {
            property('fault.id')
            property('tr.geckId')
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see what your model looks like, but I think you can do something like this:

```
Fault.createCriteria().list() {
    createAlias('tgmap', 'tg', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    eqProperty('tg.fault.id', 'id')
}
```

[Reference](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/grails-criteria-query-createalias-made-it-easy/)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. However, this is not working. I have made some corrections and edits to my question. I want to join fault and tgmap on the condition fault.id = tgmap.fault_id and not fault.id = tgmap.group_id which is happening by default.  The results of this again should get left joined to the Trace table in the end. Please suggest.